# Why does eval("2*2" + 4) in js output 48?

Tags: javascript

I understand that it evaluates a string to a number equivalent and should never be used, but I don't get why this code -

```
    var x = "2*2";
    var y = 4;
    var z = eval(x + y);
    console.log(z);
```

outputs the number 48? Shouldn't it be 8 or "44"? I also get number 48 if all inputs are strings (e.g. var y = "4").

Comment: Concatenation happens before the eval call, so you eval "2*24", which is 48

Comment: To get 8, do `eval("(2*2)+4")` or `eval("2*2")+4`, to get 44 do `eval("2*2")+"4"`

Comment: @Altareos Thnaks! I had a similar hunch. First ever question on stack overflow is a success.

Answer (score 4):

```
var x = "2*2"; // x = "2*2"
var y = 4;
var z = eval(x + y);// "2*2"+4 -> eval("2*24") ->48
console.log(z);
```

the string operation("2*2"+4) done before the eval

Answer (score 1):

To understand it, always use **typeof**

```
    var x = "2*2";
    var y = 4;
    var res = x + y;
    console.log(res); // 2*24
    console.log(typeof res); // string
    var z = eval(res);
    console.log(z); // 48
    console.log(typeof z); // number
```